# List as function parameter returning NameError: not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python. Working with `2.7` for class.
The teacher set a project in which we are to code a program that takes a piece of a Monty Python script (input by user), stores it in a list of lists, replaces a specific name in the script with the user's name and prints the revised script out to console.

The issue I am running into is in my third function `replace_name`, the `parameters are the list of lists, old name, new name`.

However, I am getting

> NameError:'word_list' is not defined

I understand that if a variable is not defined in the Main then it is local to its function.
I thought though, that by using return in the function that that information is stored to be used by subsequent functions.

Am I wrong?

```
def new_name(): #prompts for user's name. checks if input is valid
  while True:
    name = raw_input("Please enter your name.\n")
    if len(name) < 1:
      print "Invalid, please enter your name.\n"
    else:
      return name

def orig_script():#reads in script, splits into list of lists
  word_list = [] 
  script = raw_input("Please enter script, one line at a time. Enter 'done' to exit. \n")
  if len(script) < 1:
      print "Empty text field. Please try again.\n"
  while script != 'done':#splits string input,adds to list
    words = script.split()
    word_list.append(words)
    script = raw_input("Please enter script, one line at a time. Enter 'done' to exit.\n ")
    if len(script) < 1:
      print "Empty text field. Please try again.\n"
  return word_list

def replace_name(word_list,old_name,new_name):#replaces old name with new name in list. creates new list from changes.
  new_list = []
  for sentences in range(word_list):
    sentence = word_list[sentences]
    for words in range(sentece):
      word = sentence[words]
      if word == old_name:
        sentence[words] == new_name
        new_list.append(sentence)
   print new_list#debugging-change to return

new_name()
orig_script()
replace_name(word_list, Robin, new_name)
```

If my indentation is a bit off here, I apologize.
I tried to correct it from the copy/paste.
There are no indentation errors given in repl.it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 45, in <module>
NameError: name 'word_list' is not defined
```

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: Please include the full error output into the question

Comment: *by using return in the function that that information is stored to be used by subsequent functions* - Only if you actually store that returned value yourself... Where is your main function? Where are you calling these other functions?

Comment: If anything,  `sentece` is a NameError and `range()` does not take a list object... Did you mean `for sentence in word_list`? Which loops over every item  within that list

Comment: Just calling them in Main, thought it was unnecessary to create a function to call all the other functions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the rest of the code

Comment: I did not initially use range. My professor used it in his example code in class today so I changed mine to follow his example.

Comment: I bet you that you missed the length function, then...  `range(len(word_list))`

Comment: Thank you! I am sure that I did.

Comment: @Tashak `word_list = orig_script()`. Although you have various other problems in your program. `word_list` isn't defined globally when you pass it to your other function because you didn't store the return value in a variable. It only exists within that functions scope. Same for `new_name` and whatever `Robin` is supposed to be - I'm assuming you missed the quotes.

Comment: @Tashak if len(name) < 1: is redundant. You can just check `if name`. Everything in Python has a "truthiness". There's also much better way of checking this. name = raw_input(....) while not name: *ask for new name*`.

Answer (score 1):

You did not assign any of the `word_list, Robin, new_name` variables. Returning a variable of a particular name does not bind it to any type of external variable on its own, especially not one of the same name.

For example, you need to assign the return value explicitly to its own variable.

```
word_list = orig_script()
name = new_name()
replace_name(word_list, "old name", name)
```

---

Also

```
for sentences in range(len(word_list)):
    sentence = word_list[sentences]
```

Is the same as

```
for sentence in word_list:
```

Note: You do have a typo in `sentece` and this is a comparison, not an assignment `sentence[words] == new_name`

---

Bonus, I think you can rewrite `replace_name` as

```
def replace_name(word_list,old_name,new_name):
    return [[new_name if w == old_name else old_name for w in sentence] for sentence in word_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parameter in you function argument.

Ex.

```
#take the o/p of variable in another one and pass in funcation
return_val = orig_script()

old_name = ["jack", "mike" , "josh"]
new_name= ["jen" , "ros" , "chan"]

#calling replace name funcation 
replace_name(return_val,old_name,new_name)
```